# unable to send image in flutter using http

Tags: flutter, dart, telegram, telegram-bot

I am unable to send image in flutter, I have put image in `image/test.png`, it's not responding after `print(photo.path);` and running my code in **flutlab** editor online.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';

void sendPhotoToTelegram() async {
  print("sstart");

  const token = 'token';
  const url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendPhoto';
  const chatId = 1291695368;
  final photo = File('image/test.png');

  final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
  request.fields['chat_id'] = chatId.toString();

  print(photo.path);

  request.files
      .add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('photo', photo.readAsBytesSync()));

  final response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Photo sent successfully!');
  } else {
    print('Error sending photo: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}

void main() {
  sendPhotoToTelegram();
}
```

I tried sending message and it worked but I am unable to send image , I also tried other method like `fromPath` it's also not responding like that, I tried all, I also try to check google code, this also not work

```
(String filename, String url) async {
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
  request.files.add(
    http.MultipartFile(
      'picture',
      File(filename).readAsBytes().asStream(),
      File(filename).lengthSync(),
      filename: filename.split("/").last
    )
  );
  var res = await request.send();
}
```

Comment: Does the file exist (photo.existsSync())? What is the error received from API?

Comment: Try with fromPath function:
`http.MultipartFile.fromPath`

Comment: i try ` print(photo.existsSync());` its also not responding , actually i am using **flutlab** online flutter,

Comment: i try both frompath , no is working

Answer (score 0):

The `image/test.png` is in the project directory I assume. Once you run the app (in debug or release) this Dart code doesn't have access to this file. It would if you would run the script as a normal Dart program with `dart run xx.dart`.

If you want to access a file you provide in a Flutter program, add path to it to `flutter.assets` section in your `pubspec.yaml`, like so:

```yaml
# ...
flutter:
  assets:
    - image/test.png
```

And then retrieve the bytes using the following:

```dart
final photoBytes = await rootBundle.load('image/test.png');

// and then pass the bytes the same way you tried

request.files.add(
  http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'photo',
    photoBytes.buffer.asUint8List(),
  ),
);
```

Read more:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/load.html

Comment: Ok thanks for your response , but why i can't use file() any reason?